# Event when <audio> begins playing

Tags: javascript, html, audio, onload

I want a gif loader image to disappear as soon as an autoplayed audio tag starts playing ie. after it loads. Is there any way to do this with javascript?
The audio is a live stream if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [canplaythrough](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/canplaythrough) event.

```
audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() { 
    audio.play();
    // code that removes your gif loader
}, false);
```